# Redis: single big hash vs many keys

Tags: hash, redis

I have some data which has million key-value pairs. So which way is better to store them in redis, single key with super big hash which has million key-value pairs or million keys each having a value?

In my opinion, both ways seems not very good given million pairs.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Redis stores everything in a big hash table internally anyhow. So for a single node, probably not going to make a big difference.

However, as soon as you need to scale and add clustering, that one key that contains *your* hash and that has everything will always be on the same shard. Which means clustering isn't really doing anything.

I'd go for the proliferation of keys.

Comment: Also, you can expire keys, while you cannot expire fields in hash.

Comment: In my context, million key-value pairs  is related to single rule such as the same date. So if we have cluster, million keys is still better?

Comment: Depends on how many rules you have, but if there are more than a handful, it probably doesn't matter.